# integral basis for an arbitrary cubic Galois field

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I wonder where I can find some information (possible a book) about finding an integral basis for cubic Galois fields? I know that for pure cubic fields there exists a simple criterion according to which this can easily be done but I wonder how do we find such bases generally for cubic Galois fields?

Any suggestions/tips appreciated.